# nested Navigation Frame in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I created one master page with navigation frame. In a child page also containing one navigation frame once Child page loaded the outer next prev buttons are not working...

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the hyperlinks, create a button with a click event. Then call

```
 this.subframe.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/AboutContent/AboutPage1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

subframe is the name of your nested frame. That should do it

you may also have to set this property in your nested frame:

```
 JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
```